# Conditional formatting formula QUERY() inside UNIQUE()

Tags: google-sheets

I want to conditionally format rows that have values in their G or H column that are unique among rows with the same B and C column values. I tried writing a query inside of the unique function that selects rows where B and C equal the previous row. Here is my attempt:

```
= AND(
$C3 = $C2, $B3 = $B2, OR(
$G3 = UNIQUE(
QUERY(
A2:J417, "select G where B = B - 1 AND C = C - 1"
   )
  ), 
$H3 = UNIQUE(
QUERY(
A2:J417, "select H where B = B - 1 AND C = C - 1"
   )
  )
 )
)
```

Could someone help me with this?

Sample data:

```
    A      B      C     D     E       F      G   H
    52  120 min Fe (2+) 3   0.229   0.496   10x 16x
    53  120 min Fe (2+) 4   0.240   0.507   10x 16x
    54  120 min Fe (2+) 5   0.226   0.499   10x 16x
    55  120 min Fe (2+) 6   0.228   0.486   10x 16x
    56  120 min Fe (2+) 7   0.249   0.465   10x 20x
    57  120 min Fe (3+) 1   0.223   0.429   5x  10x
    58  120 min Fe (3+) 2   0.236   0.468   5x  10x
    59  120 min Fe (3+) 3   0.223   0.418   5x  10x
    60  120 min Fe (3+) 4   0.229   0.446   5x  10x
```

Row 5 would be highlighted because it is 120 min, Fe (2+) but has a different concentration for column H.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide some sample data plz?

Comment: Hi, I'm able to retrieve the correct values using the following formula `=QUERY(QUERY(A1:H10, "select count(A),B,C,G,H group by B,C,G,H "), "select * where Col1 <= 1")` However this won't work on conditional formatting. This can certainly be achieved using Apps Scripts. Are you ok with working with Apps Scripts?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(
 COUNTIFS($B$1:$B&$C$1:$C&$G$1:$G&$H$1:$H, $B1&$C1&$G1&$H1, ROW($B$1:$B), ">="&ROW($B1))=  
 COUNTIFS($B$1:$B&$C$1:$C&$G$1:$G&$H$1:$H, $B1&$C1&$G1&$H1, ROW($B$1:$B), "<="&ROW($B1)))
```

[image]

Comment: It didn't apply the formatting-- can a conditional formatting formula handle an array (I think INDEX() returns an array here)?

Comment: @AdrianneKSeiden answer updated, try now